# Add PHP into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to add some PHP into JavaScript, however, the one I have at the moment does not work and was wondering if you could help.

This is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 setTimeout( function() {
  $("body").addClass("ready");
 }, 1700);
 setTimeout( function() {
  $(".splash h1").html("Hi <?php echo '$first_name'?>");
  setTimeout( function() {
   $(".splash h1").html("Welcome to your Profile");
  }, 1500);
 }, 900);
});
```

The variable `first_name` is already defined and fully working on the PHP page it will display on.

Here is the PHP code

```
    <?php
/* Displays user information and some useful messages */
session_start();

// Check if user is logged in using the session variable
if ( $_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 ) {
  $_SESSION['message'] ='<br>You must be logged in before accessing that page!';
  header("location: login.php");
}
else {
  $title = $_SESSION['title'];
  $first_name = $_SESSION['first_name'];
  $last_name = $_SESSION['last_name'];
  $email = $_SESSION['email'];
  $school_name = $_SESSION['school_name'];
  $class = $_SESSION['class'];
  $school_admin = $_SESSION['school_admin'];
  $position = $_SESSION['position'];
  $active = $_SESSION['active'];
  $staff = $_SESSION['staff'];
  $grav_hash = md5("$email");
}
?>
```

Comment: `'$first_name'` remove the quotes

Comment: Done - still not working, only pops up with 'Hi'.

Comment: You didn't add the `;` at the end bud

Comment: What is the file extension?

Comment: Look at the console and see if there are any errors in that piece of the code

Comment: @Samuel where should the `;` go?

Comment: `<?php echo $first_name; ?>`

Comment: Doe that, still only displays 'Hi' and then moves onto the next bit.

Comment: @Tom, is this piece of code been written on separate JS file or in any php file?

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan separate JS file

Comment: One that is not run through the php parser, presumably.  Therein lies the problem.

Comment: @Tom, in order to make this work you need to put it on the php file. In separate JS file it won't work.

Comment: Variables are not carried over for separate files loaded over HTTP. Make sure you define it in the separate JS file.

Comment: Great! Thank you!! It works now @JesseSchokker

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semi colons around the variable, and make sure it is defined.

```
<?php

$first_name = "Tom";

?> 

$(document).ready( function() {
     setTimeout( function() {
      $("body").addClass("ready");
     }, 1700);
     setTimeout( function() {
      $(".splash h1").html("Hi <?php echo $first_name; ?>");
      setTimeout( function() {
       $(".splash h1").html("Welcome to your Profile");
      }, 1500);
     }, 900);
    });
```

Comment: The variable is defined in the php file it is used on, do I have to define it on this js file?

Comment: You do have to define it on the JS file if it is a separate JS file.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using an external .js file it's not possible unless you change something in .htacess file. There's another easier way.
Use a .php file and add at the beginning `header("Content-type: text/javascript");` and with a simple `echo'your js code';` write your script and you'll be able to mix php and javascript in a single file.

If you're using a .php file and using `<script></script>` just use `<?php $yourphpcode; ?>` and add your code.

I hope I've  helped you with this :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  setTimeout( function() {
  $("body").addClass("ready");
  }, 1700);
  setTimeout( function() {
  $(".splash h1").html("Hi <?php echo '{$first_name}'; ?>");
  setTimeout( function() {
  $(".splash h1").html("Welcome to your Profile");
  }, 1500);
}, 900);
});
```

You have not ended the echo with semi-colon. This is the error.

Comment: Added the semi-colon however not working still, only displays 'Hi' and then moves onto 'Welcome to your profile'.

Comment: can you show your php code as well.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong @mayankjain

Comment: Added the PHP code to question @mayankjain

Comment: corrected it @JesseSchokker

Comment: Nice copy of my answer lmao

Comment: is the PHP code in different file? @Tom

Comment: well there are not many ways to echo out variables, but still I'll change it to something new if that pleases you @JesseSchokker

Comment: I hope you are happy now @JesseSchokker LOL!

Comment: Good job, you made a nice meme.